# Finding z transform of this function.

Tags: z-transform

I need to find the z-transform of the function $t^{a}e^{-bt}$. Though it did appear easy to me initially but i cannot figure out how to do so. **The problem is that 'a' can be a non-integer.** (t can be thought of as a discrete time variable) Can someone please guide me or give some hints. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess we are dealing with one-side transform here. Then (assuming $a>0$)
$$F(z)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} t^a e^{-bt} z^{-t}=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{w^{t}}{t^{-a}}={\rm Li}_{-a}(w)$$ where $w=z^{-1}\,e^{-b}$ and 
 ${\rm Li}_s(\cdot)$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). This has no nice simple closed form expression for arbitrary $a$. Is this howework? Are you sure you got it right?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems good. Yes its kind of homework.